# Fail without logging passwords in plain text

Tags: security, chef-infra

So we have code that looks something like this:

```
template my_template do
     #stuff
     variables({"password": data_bag["password"]})
end
```

This code is all fine and good, until later, the template fails.  When it does, it dumps everything, including the password, that was directed into the erb template.  This data is automatically logged in plain text which is automatically combed later by some other scripts, which, naturally, makes me uncomfortable.

Barring writing perfect code all the time, is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: If you change the password, chef will also print the diff in the log, showing in plain text the old and new password. I see no easy way, you may use a ruby block, creating the template withing it and catching the fail to just log the failure without dumping the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new `sensitive` attribute.  From the [docs:](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html)

```
sensitive - Use to ensure that sensitive resource data is not logged by the chef-client. Default value: false. This setting only applies to the execute, file and template resources
```

So something like this:

```
template my_template do
  #stuff
  variables({"password": data_bag["password"]})
  sensitive true
end
```

This is a new chef 12 feature, and I've not used it.  So I can't promise it will solve your problems, but the docs suggest it will.